# Infinite Loop fetching data in useEffect with React Native Hooks and Redux

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, redux, use-effect

I have not been able to solve an issue related to infinite loops with React Hooks and Redux in useEffect.
I have read many articles about useEffect (https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/, https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies, https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data) and haven't still been able to avoid this infinite loop.

I do have a an app with 2 Tabs, one of them is a list of transports and the other is a summary of the active transport.
The idea is to have a List of transports that can be booked, and whenever it is done, update the active transport in the other tab.
The cycle of the app should be something like:

- Log in App -> No active transport. (Dispatch an action to fetch data).
- Click on List of Transports Tab (Dispatch an action to fetch list of transports).
- Book a transport (Dispatch an action to update the active transport with the one selected)
- Click on Active transport Tab and see the information of the transport.

The idea behind is that whenever the state of the active transport is updated, the Active transport Screen must be re-render because it is a dependency in useEffect, but what it does is trigger an infinite loop.

I understand why. In order to fetch the active transport from the database, I have the typical sequence of dispatches (Request, Success, Error) that change the state of the dependency. And this trigger the infinite loop because everytime the state is changing, the screen is re-rendered and I have the same problem with the list of transports.

Even knowing that, I am still not able to know how to solve it.

The active screen Im using is the next one:

ActiveTransport Screen:

```
export default function ActiveTransportScreen() {

const dispatch = useDispatch();
const isLoading = useSelector(state => state.activeTransport.isLoading);
const transport = useSelector(state => state.activeTransport.transport);

useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(activeTransportActions.getActiveTransport());
}, [transport]);

if (isLoading) {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>Cargando</Text>
        </View>
    )
}

if (!transport) {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>No hay ningun transporte activo</Text>
        </View>
    )
}


return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.item}>
            <Text>Lugar de retirada: {transport.removalPlace} </Text>
        </View>

        <View style={styles.containerButtons}/>
        <TouchableHighlight
            style={{...styles.openButton, backgroundColor: "#2196F3"}}
            onPress={() => {
            }}
        >
            <Text style={modalStyles.textStyle}>Completar hito</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>

        <TouchableHighlight
            style={{...styles.openButton, backgroundColor: "#2196F3"}}
            onPress={() => {
                dispatch(activeTransportActions.cancelTransport());
            }}
        >
            <Text style={modalStyles.textStyle}>Cancelar</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
    </View>
);
```

}

The idea behind is being able to re-render the ActiveScreen everytime the active transport state is updated. And this can be done from the list of transports.

```
export default function TransportList() {

const dispatch = useDispatch();

const isLoading = useSelector(state => state.transportList.isLoading);
const transportsTablesList = useSelector(state => state.transportList.transports);
const isRefreshing = useSelector(state => state.transportList.isRefreshing);
const modalVisible = useSelector(state => state.modalTransportReducer.modalVisible);
const userActiveTransportId = useSelector(state => state.activeTransport.id);



const onRefresh = React.useCallback(() => {
    dispatch(transportActions.refreshTransportList());
}, []);

useEffect( () => {
    dispatch(transportActions.getAll());
}, [transportsTablesList ]);


if (isLoading) {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>Cargando</Text>
        </View>
    )
}

if (modalVisible) {
    return (
        <ModalTransport/>
    );
}

if(userActiveTransportId){
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>¡Ya tienes un transporte activo!</Text>
        </View>
    )
}

return (
    <View style={styles.container}>

        <ScrollView horizontal={true}
                    refreshControl={<RefreshControl refreshing={isRefreshing} onRefresh={onRefresh}/>}>
            <FlatList
                data={transportsTablesList}
                ListHeaderComponent={HeaderListTransport}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
                renderItem={({item}) => (RowListTransport(item))}
            />
        </ScrollView>
    </View>
);
```

}

```
    const initialState =
    {
        isLoading: false,
        id: null,
        transport: null,
        accomplishment: null,
        state: null,
        isRefreshing: false
    };

export function activeTransport(state = initialState, action) {

switch (action.type) {

    case activeTransportConstants.BOOK_TRANSPORT_REQUEST:
        return {
            ...state,
            isLoading: true,
            id: null,
        };

    case activeTransportConstants.BOOK_TRANSPORT_SUCCESS:
        return {
            ...state,
            isLoading: false,
            transport: action.transport,
            transportId: action.transportId
        };


    case activeTransportConstants.BOOK_TRANSPORT_ERROR:
        return {
            ...state,
            isLoading: false,
            transport: null,
            transportId: null
        };

    case activeTransportConstants.GET_ACTIVE_TRANSPORT_REQUEST:
        return {
            ...state,
            isLoading: true,
        };

    case activeTransportConstants.GET_ACTIVE_TRANSPORT_SUCCESS:
        return {
            ...state,
            isLoading: false,
            id: action.payload.id,
            transport: action.payload.transport,
            accomplishment: action.payload.accomplishment,
            state: action.payload.state
        };
```

Everytime the user book a transport the next Modal dispatch an action to update the database and get the active transport, therefore, the tab ActiveTransport should be re-rendered with the information of the new transport.

```
export default function ModalTransport() {

const dispatch = useDispatch();
const modalVisible = useSelector(state => state.modalTransportReducer.modalVisible);
const transportSelected = useSelector(state => state.modalTransportReducer.transportSelected);

return(
    <View style={modalStyles.centeredView}>
        <Modal
            animationType="slide"
            transparent={true}
            visible={modalVisible}
            onRequestClose={() =>
                {
                        dispatch(transportActions.refreshTransportList());
                        // dispatch(activeTransportActions.getActiveTransport());
                }
            }
        >
            <View style={modalStyles.centeredView}>
                <View style={modalStyles.modalView}>
                    <Text style={modalStyles.modalText}>Transporte</Text>
                    <Text style={{width: 300, height: 50}}><Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}> Lugar de retirada:</Text> {transportSelected.transportEntity.removalPlace}</Text>
                    <Text style={{width: 300, height: 50}}><Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Lugar de devolución: </Text> {transportSelected.transportEntity.returnPlace}</Text>
                    <Text style={{width: 300, height: 50}}><Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Cliente: </Text>{transportSelected.transportEntity.customer}</Text>
                    <Text style={{width: 300, height: 50}}><Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}> Carga: </Text>{transportSelected.transportEntity.load}</Text>
                    <Text style={{width: 300, height: 50}}><Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Fecha: </Text> {transportSelected.transportEntity.date} </Text>
                    <Text style={{width: 300, height: 50}}><Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Fecha de caducidad: </Text>{transportSelected.transportEntity.expiryDate} </Text>

                    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                        <TouchableHighlight
                            style={{...modalStyles.openButton, backgroundColor: "#2196F3"}}
                            onPress={() => {
                                dispatch(transportActions.bookTransport(transportSelected.id));
                                dispatch(modalTransportActions.closeModal());
                            }}
                        >
                            <Text style={modalStyles.textStyle}>Reservar</Text>
                        </TouchableHighlight>

                        <TouchableHighlight
                            style={{...modalStyles.openButton, backgroundColor: "#2196F3"}}
                            onPress={() => {
                                dispatch(modalTransportActions.closeModal())
                            }}
                        >
                            <Text style={modalStyles.textStyle}>Cancelar</Text>
                        </TouchableHighlight>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
        </Modal>
    </View>
);
```

}

I don't know exactly what should I do. I understand that transport is the only dependency in useEffect, and this must be re-rendered everytime changes, but I don't know how to isolate the sequence of request, success, error that change the state everytime.
I  just select the transport from the state, not the other parts.

I have tried with useCallback and useMemo but still have the same problem.

What should I do?

I hope you can help me.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't see where `transport` is used in the effect, why is it a dependency? If any logic in an effect hook ultimately updates any values in the dependency array ***and*** there is no conditional test *on that value* then **OFC** it will cause an infinite loop to occur. What do you want to trigger updating the active transport in state?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I do dispatch an action to update the transport from a Modal in the ListTransport. I have added the modal. The idea is to get the list of transports, book the transport and get it from the ActiveTransportScreen inmediately after booked.

Comment: I guess I could have specified more clearly, that in `ActiveTransportScreen` in the effect hook to `dispatch(activeTransportActions.getActiveTransport());` you added `transport` to the dependency list but `transport` isn't used in the effect hook. The hook callback is triggered when `transport` updates *and* directly dispatches an action that appears to eventually update `transport`. This creates a cycle and infinite render loop. My last question was "What specifically in `ActiveTransportScreen` do you want to trigger dispatching `getActiveTransport`? Seems the component already has that info.

Comment: You're right. I think I don't know exactly how to re-render the ActiveScreen when the transport state is changed from the modal. I thought putting transport as a dependency of the useEffect would re-render the screen whenever the state is updated, even though maybe it is not a dependency. But then I don't understand how should I do it. How can re-render the screen when transport state is changed? Thanks.